# Adding new DataRow doesn't add row to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource, datarow

I have been beating my head against the wall on this one and I haven't been able to get it working - so I figured I'd ask here just in case it's something simple.

Basically, I have a DataGridView and I'm trying to add a row to it programatically.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
boundBookDataSet.LoadBoundBook.AddLoadBoundBookRow(
    null, null, null, null, null, DateTime.Now, null, null, null, 
    false, false, -1, null, -1, -1);
```

I've also tried calling AcceptChanges on both the DataSet as well as the new DataRow after adding the row, and I've also tried calling Refresh on the DataGridView.

Anyway, no matter what I do, I end up with boundBookDataSet.LoadBoundBook.Count==70 and loadBoundBookBindingSource.Count==69.  My DataGridView won't pick up the new row since it isn't reflected in the binding source (at least that's my guess).

Sadly, this was working - but I made a huge change and can't figure out what broke it.  The code that is broken didn't change at all...

If anyone has any idea how to resolve this, I would seriously appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  I figured it out. :)

As I was looking through the fields in my BindingSource once again, I realized I had the Filter field set.  If I remove the filter, the loadBoundBookBindingSource.Count gets incremented correctly and the DataGridView picks up the new record.

Basically, it looks like I need to clear the filter, add the record, then set the filter again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its winforms your talking about an answer to the problem is available on this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/f12158b3-4510-47cb-b152-409489c3a51a/

Comment: Aha!  I figured it out. :)

As I was looking through the fields in my BindingSource once again, I realized I had the Filter field set.  If I remove the filter, the loadBoundBookBindingSource.Count gets incremented correctly and the DataGridView picks up the new record.

Basically, it looks like I need to clear the filter, add the record, then set the filter again.